# Tweepy Python not posting

Tags: python, tweepy

Could someone please tell me why this isn't posting a status to my twitter account? I have been trying to do a uni project where I post to twitter from Python, but I couldn't get the basics working.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

post = ("testing")
#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        #print(data)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)


api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status('hey, im posting this using python')
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is okay!!

1. Check out the app permissions (you need read/write permissions).
2. Which version of tweepy are you using? This code works for me :

   ```
   import tweepy2

   #Consumer keys and access tokens
   consumer_key = 'X'
   consumer_secret = 'X'
   access_token = 'X'
   access_token_secret = 'X'

   # OAuth process
   auth = tweepy2.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

   # Creation of the actual interface
   api = tweepy2.API(auth)

   # Post status
   api.update_status('Good morning from stackOverflow :)!')
   ```
3. I'm using tweepy2 (https://bitbucket.org/sakito/tweepy) which allow you to use private proxy, but anyway, just change tweepy2 to tweepy (if you're using this one http://www.tweepy.org/) and it should work :)
4. If still doesn't work, try to regenerate the keys.